# Cardview in Android - Can different cards be used to collect user information?

Tags: android, mobile-development

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Basically I am developing a medication reminder app for Android.

Rather than create a really basic UI, I really like the idea of having each question in a card.

For example, in the first card I would like to have a TextView to say what the card is for and then an EditText for user input.

Most cards would also have a TextView but a different kind of way for the user to input the required information, for example a Timepicker or Spinner.

All I would really like to know is whether or not it is possible to use the Cardview in this manner?

Once again, thank you so much for reading my question.

Sarah

Comment: Yes, it can... bearing in mind that `CardView` has little to do with any of this. *All* `CardView` does is wrap an existing set of widgets in a container that provides a rounded rectangle border with a drop shadow. That's it.

Comment: So the cards are basically just a cosmetic feature. It makes sense now. Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: are you asking from design point of view?

Comment: Most of the tutorials that I have seen have sets of identically formatted cards. I just wanted to know if it was possible to design each card in a different way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not? You can do however, you like. Here is [material design standards](https://material.io/guidelines/), and [cards](https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#cards-usage). You can find specifications etc. I didn't see this case but I do it anyways.

Comment: The links you have provided look really helpful. Thank you so much for replying.